# Pangesture Fails and then stuck on view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

My app consists of a deck of cards. Each card has a scrollview that allows you to look at images associated with that card. You can drag to look at another card in the deck via pan gesture. Unfortunately, if you don't do a clean drag the first time (like if you drag half way and then lift your finger off), the app gets stuck on that card. You can scroll up and down, but you won't be able to drag. When you try, you just move backgroundScrollView around within the superview(so swiping right means you see the grey, right margins between scrollview and superview).

This is the method that UIPanGestureRecognizer calls:

```
-(void)beingDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"I am being dragged");
    xFromCenter = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].x; //%%% positive for right swipe, negative for left
    yFromCenter = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].y; //%%% positive for up, negative for down

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
            //%%% just started swiping
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            self.backgroundScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            self.originalPoint = self.center;
            _backgroundScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            _backgroundScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
            likeBadge.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            likeBadge.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
            passBadge.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            passBadge.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
            reviewButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
            reviewButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
            break;
        };
            //%%% in the middle of a swipe
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            //%%% dictates rotation (see ROTATION_MAX and ROTATION_STRENGTH for details)
            CGFloat rotationStrength = MIN(xFromCenter / ROTATION_STRENGTH, ROTATION_MAX);

            //%%% degree change in radians
            CGFloat rotationAngel = (CGFloat) (ROTATION_ANGLE * rotationStrength);

            //%%% amount the height changes when you move the card up to a certain point
            CGFloat scale = MAX(1 - fabsf(rotationStrength) / SCALE_STRENGTH, SCALE_MAX);

            //%%% move the object's center by center + gesture coordinate
            self.center = CGPointMake(self.originalPoint.x + xFromCenter, self.originalPoint.y + yFromCenter);

            //%%% rotate by certain amount
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngel);

            //%%% scale by certain amount
            CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);

            //%%% apply transformations
            self.transform = scaleTransform;

            [self updateOverlay:xFromCenter:yFromCenter];

            break;
        };
            //%%% let go of the card
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            self.backgroundScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            [self afterSwipeAction];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:{
            self.backgroundScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:{
            self.backgroundScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:{
            self.backgroundScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been to set

```
_backgroundScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

whereas before it was set to YES. This does mean that scrollView now leaks out of the view when you swipe, but that's for another post...